# How To Open A Custom File Extension as .txt Using Python

Tags: python, file

I'm making a code that will create a new form of file extension (in this case .aobj, which will be used to help me make games easier).  I tried using the code below (this is using Python)

```
print "Starting..."
info = []
part1 = open('temporary.aobj', 'r')
part2 = part1.readlines()
for line in part2:
   info.append(line)
print info
```

Instead of this printing out what's actually in the file when i used notepad, it shows this:

```
Starting...
[[...], [...], [...]]
```

I'm guessing this is because it doesn't recognize the file format, but how can i fix this?

Comment: You are appending to a python list, what output are you expecting if not a list?

Comment: What is the file format if not text?  File extensions are only conventions.  They do not impose or guarantee any particular format.

Comment: By the way, the part of Python you're using (the basic file I/O library) neither knows nor cares about file formats. It just reads bytes.

Comment: The problem is not that I'm not getting a string, that is the literal output, with the dots included.  Inside of it is a few lines of information, but instead it prints the dots.

Comment: I would try to reproduce this, but you are not saying what the file format is, neither are you supplying any sample data.  You mention Microsoft's Notepad, but you do not say which format you are saving the file in.    We need the way you are writing data to the file, the file extension is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing info, which is an object somewhat similar to nested list.

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
print (a)
```

This prints
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]

```
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

This prints 
[1, 2]
[3, 4]

```
for i in a:
    for j in i:
            print(j,end=' ')
    print()
```

This prints
1 2
3 4

Which is what you seem to want.
So, instead of printing the info object as is, do something like this-

```
for line in info:
    for word in line:
            print(word,end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: You have some typos in the last `print()` functions. Regarding your PS, that's not true at all, in Python2 `print` is a statement (no brackets needed), while in Python3 `print()` is a function. The for loops are compatible though.

Comment: The `print()` function calls in Python 2 require `from __future__ import print_function`.  The Python 2 `print` statement does not have named parameters.

Comment: @cdarke print() doesn't call the print_function...its just seen as a normal bracket if not this would work out of the box `print(11234, end='')`

Comment: my issue is that it is literally printing the dots, even while i'm trying to get info from the file.  I added words, and for my purposes it doesn't really matter if it's in that format, what I need is for it to print the ASCII that I put in the file using Notepad

Comment: @danidee: it is not the brackets that are the problem in Python 2, it is the named parameter.  In Python 2 `print(11234, end='')` gives a Syntax Error pointing at the `=`.  The Python 2 version would be `print 11234,` (the trailing comma puts a space on the end instead of a newline).

Comment: @NetherMan Oh sorry. I didn't realize that the dots were literally being printed (and sorry for the very delayed response).

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting and found out that it would allow you to read the format properly as long as you wrote the info using python's write() function.  As so:

```
file = open('temporary.aobj', 'r+')
file.write('foo')
info = file.readlines()
lines = []
for line in info:
   lines.append(line)
print lines
```

This will print out the info that is inside of it, it's slightly slower because you are required to write all the info using python.

Comment: There is nothing peculiar or special about Python's `write` function. This merely suggests that your file is not a valid plain text file to begin with.